# Gmail address book in Evolution does not work

Tags: evolution, contacts, gmail, google, address-book

I added my Gmail address book to Evolution, but it gives me an error every time, even when choosing "use secure connection" in the address book options. The error is (I translated it on my own):

> unable to open address book. This is because you entered a wrong URI or the server is unavailable at the moment. Details: cannot open book: source already loaded!

Sometimes, when I click the button 'reject error', it does load the address book but when I return to Evolution after a while, it gives me the same error and sometimes I cannot load the address book. This is very annoying since I have to use Evolution a lot.

Comment: Not immediately a solution to your problem, but have you considered changing from evolution to thunderbird? I suppose you use 12.04(?) I also have a gmail account and changed from evolution to thunderbird upon upgrading from Lucid to Pangolin. Works very elegantly, and with lightning (the calendar addon), your gmail calender is also synced. Should give it a try. Sorry I can't help you with your immediate problem, though (another belgian)

Comment: I tried it, but didn't succeed to get the gmail calendar plugin to work (I installed it but didn't find it in the menu's then). That's when I moved back to evolution since I'm using it for over a year. Thanks Belgian colleague.

Comment: I have not experienced any  problem while importing my address book exported as Outlook CSV file from Gmail to Evolution 3.12.9.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are experiencing one of these bugs:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libgdata/+bug/755043

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evolution-data-server/+bug/1010349